Autoclicker in java
I am trying to make it so after I press the start button, it does the clicks when left mouse button is being held down, but right now its not clicking at all when I hold left mouse button.
package GUI;

import Engine.AutoClicker;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

    private UI ui;
    private AutoClicker autoClicker;

    public EventHandler(UI ui, AutoClicker autoClicker) {
        this.ui = ui;
        this.autoClicker = autoClicker;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(ui.getStartButton())) {
            try {
                int minCPS = Integer.parseInt(ui.getMinCPSFieldText());
                int maxCPS = Integer.parseInt(ui.getMaxCPSFieldText());
                autoClicker.setMinCPS(minCPS);
                autoClicker.setMaxCPS(maxCPS);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ui, "Please enter valid integers for CPS values.");
                return;
            }
            
            autoClicker.startClicking();
            System.out.println("start");
        } else if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(ui.getStopButton())) {
            autoClicker.stopClicking();
            System.out.println("stop");
        }
    }
}

package Engine;

import javax.swing.*;
import GUI.UI;

public class Engine {

    private Thread UIthread, clickerThread;
    private UI ui;
    private AutoClicker autoClicker;

    public Engine(int width, int height) {
        autoClicker = new AutoClicker();

        ui = new UI(width, height, autoClicker);
        ui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ui.setVisible(true);

        // UI class already adds the AutoClicker as a MouseListener

        UIthread = new Thread(ui);
        UIthread.start();

        clickerThread = new Thread(autoClicker);
        clickerThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Engine(500, 300);
    }
}

package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import Engine.AutoClicker;

public class UI extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public int width, height;
    private JButton start, stop;
    private JTextField minCPSField, maxCPSField;
    private AutoClicker autoClicker;

    public UI(int width, int height, AutoClicker autoClicker) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.autoClicker = autoClicker;
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(width, height);

        // Add AutoClicker as a MouseListener
        this.addMouseListener(autoClicker);
    }

    public void init() {
        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30);
        add(start);

        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.setBounds(320, 100, 100, 30);
        add(stop);

        JLabel minCPSLabel = new JLabel("Min CPS:");
        minCPSLabel.setBounds(30, 50, 100, 30);
        add(minCPSLabel);

        minCPSField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(autoClicker.getMinCPS()));
        minCPSField.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);
        add(minCPSField);

        JLabel maxCPSLabel = new JLabel("Max CPS:");
        maxCPSLabel.setBounds(250, 50, 100, 30);
        add(maxCPSLabel);

        maxCPSField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(autoClicker.getMaxCPS()));
        maxCPSField.setBounds(320, 50, 100, 30);
        add(maxCPSField);

        EventHandler eHandler = new EventHandler(this, autoClicker);
        start.addActionListener(eHandler);
        stop.addActionListener(eHandler);
        minCPSField.addActionListener(eHandler);
        maxCPSField.addActionListener(eHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
    }

    public String getMinCPSFieldText() {
        return minCPSField.getText();
    }

    public String getMaxCPSFieldText() {
        return maxCPSField.getText();
    }

    public JButton getStartButton() {
        return start;
    }

    public JButton getStopButton() {
        return stop;
    }
}

package Engine;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class AutoClicker extends MouseAdapter implements Runnable {

    private Robot robot;
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean leftMouseButtonPressed = false; // Add this flag
    private int minCPS = 10;
    private int maxCPS = 20;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public AutoClicker() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (running && leftMouseButtonPressed) { 
                clickMouse();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void clickMouse() {
        try {
            int delay = getRandomCPS();
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getRandomCPS() {
        return 1000 / (minCPS + random.nextInt(maxCPS - minCPS + 1));
    }

    public void startClicking() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void stopClicking() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void setMinCPS(int minCPS) {
        this.minCPS = minCPS;
    }

    public void setMaxCPS(int maxCPS) {
        this.maxCPS = maxCPS;
    }

    public int getMinCPS() {
        return minCPS;
    }

    public int getMaxCPS() {
        return maxCPS;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            leftMouseButtonPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            leftMouseButtonPressed = false;
        }
    }
}

I tried adding the things in the AutoClicker like MouseEvent but I am not familiar with this stuff and had no luck, I am failing to change the value of leftMouseButtonPressed = true by holding down left click.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.


I am trying to make it so after I press the start button, it does the clicks when left mouse button is being held down,

It's not exactly clear to what you are actually clicking on, so, I have to assume it's everything within the form which I should think, makes the code a little heavier. I'm not sure about in automation but in Swing it would just be a play on the MousePressed and MouseReleased events for all components along with a boolean flag to indicate when the Left Mouse Button is down and, a timer to play a Click.wav audio file every so many milliseconds depending upon what is desired for the cycle time.
Below is a Java runnable demo application which demonstrates how this can be done in Swing. This demo requires a resources sub-directory within your project src directory. Store your Click WAV file there and apply the correct file name within code for the resourcePath member variable. Read the comments in code:
package leftmousebuttonhelddowndemo;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class LeftMouseButtonHeldDownDemo {

    /* Name of the .wav file in the /src/resources directory.
       This file will be played whether the application is 
       run from the IDE or a compressed JAR file:        */
    private String resourcePath = "resources/Click.wav";

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton startButton;
    private Clip clip;
    private Timer clickTimer;
    private int clickInitialDelay = 1000;       // 1000 Milliseconds (1 second):
    private int clickDelay = 800;               // 800 Milliseconds:
    private boolean leftButtonPressed = false;

    public LeftMouseButtonHeldDownDemo() {
        initForm();
        
        /* ActionPerformed event for Start/Stop Button. This button
           continuously toggles from Start to Stop and then to Start
           again upon every selection.        */
        startButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            if (clickTimer != null) {
                clickTimer.stop();
                clickTimer = null;
                startButton.setText("START 'Left Mouse Held Down Clicking'");
                return;
            }
            startButton.setText("STOP 'Left Mouse Held Down Clicking'");
            clickTimer = new Timer(clickDelay, e -> playClick());
            clickTimer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        });
        
        /* Create a custom MouseListener to pick up on only the 
           MousePressed and MouseReleased events. This listener
           will be applied to all JFrame components:        */
        MouseAdapter formMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
                    leftButtonPressed = true;
                    Component source = evt.getComponent();
                    System.out.println("Left mouse button pressed on: " + 
                                        source.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    // If clickTimer is instantiated then start the timer:
                    if (clickTimer != null) {
                        clickTimer.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
                    leftButtonPressed = false;
                    Component source = evt.getComponent();
                    System.out.println("Left mouse button released on: " + 
                                        source.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    // If clickTimer is instantiated and the timmer is running then, stop the timer:
                    if (clickTimer != null && clickTimer.isRunning()) {
                        clickTimer.stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        
        // Add the formMouseListener (above) to all our JFrame form components!
        addMouseListenerToAllFormComponents(frame, formMouseListener);
    }
    
    /* This is a recursive method which adds the formMouseListener 
       to all our JFrame form components!            */
    private static void addMouseListenerToAllFormComponents(Container container, MouseAdapter mouseListener) {
        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            component.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                addMouseListenerToAllFormComponents((Container) component, mouseListener);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics 
           unless we really want them:        */
        new LeftMouseButtonHeldDownDemo().startDemo(args);
    }

    private void startDemo(String[] args) {
        // Display the GUI when EDT is finished:
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setSize(450, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // Center to Screen:
        });
    }

    // Create the GUI:
    private void initForm() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse Left Button Held Down Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("<html>Select the Start button to begin Left Button Held Down Clicking.<br>"
                      + "Left-Click or, Left-Click and Hold <b>anywhere</b> in the JFrame form.<br>"
                      + "Also, look at your IDE's console output while clicking or click<br>and "
                      + "holding.<br><br>You can select the button again to Stop Left Button Held "
                      + "Down<br>Clicking.<br><br><br><br></html>");
        panel.add(label);
        startButton = new JButton("START 'Left Mouse Held Down Clicking'");
        panel.add(startButton);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
    private void playClick() {
        /* Get the class loader. This will allow us to run the Click.wav
           file from either the IDE or when the app is compiled to a JAR
           file since the wav file is in resources (/src/resources):                              */
        ClassLoader classLoader = LeftMouseButtonHeldDownDemo.class.getClassLoader();

        // Get the InputStream for the .wav file
        try (InputStream audioSrc = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) {
            if (audioSrc == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File can not be found: " + resourcePath);
            }

            // Convert the input stream to an AudioInputStream
            try (AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioSrc)) {
                if (clip != null && clip.isRunning()) {
                    clip.stop();
                }
                // Get a Clip object
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                // Open the clip with the audio stream
                clip.open(audioStream);

                // Start playing the clip
                clip.start();

                // Keep the program running till the audio finishes playing
                clip.addLineListener(event -> {
                    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        clip.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Just Getters:
    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public Clip getClip() {
        return clip;
    }

    public Timer getClickTimer() {
        return clickTimer;
    }

    public boolean isLeftButtonPressed() {
        return leftButtonPressed;
    }

    // Getters & Setters:
    public String getResourcePath() {
        return resourcePath;
    }

    public void setResourcePath(String resourcePath) {
        this.resourcePath = resourcePath;
    }

    public int getClickInitialDelay() {
        return clickInitialDelay;
    }

    public void setClickInitialDelay(int clickInitialDelay) {
        this.clickInitialDelay = clickInitialDelay;
    }

    public int getClickDelay() {
        return clickDelay;
    }

    public void setClickDelay(int clickDelay) {
        this.clickDelay = clickDelay;
    }
}

